# Eclipse Repository as archive

Tags: eclipse, p2

I have a job that generates a local aggregated P2 repository based on all the external repositories we use in our product (like juno, 3.8, mylyn, xtext, orbit, ...). The resulting (local) repository is rather big, but makes our builds way faster.

In order to retrieve the content of the remote repositories, I currently use the p2 mirror application. This is a bit slow, so I wondered if anybody know of zipped archives of the various p2 repositories of Eclipse? I have found zips for orbit, but nothing else.

Comment: often the project specific download sites contain zipped repos https://www.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/downloads/ https://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/downloads/ http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/

Comment: did you try b3 site aggregator https://www.eclipse.org/b3/

Comment: @Hishamkh no, I have not tried b3 or any other aggregater. I plan to do some tests against Nexus, but that is still the future.